# Module attribute mysteriously appears

Tags: python

```
$ python
Python 3.8.10 (default, Nov 14 2022, 12:59:47) 
[GCC 9.4.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import urllib
>>> urllib.request
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: module 'urllib' has no attribute 'request'
>>> urllib.request
<module 'urllib.request' from '/usr/lib/python3.8/urllib/request.py'>
```

Why is `urllib.request` recognized as an attribute the *second* time I try to access it?

Comment: `urllib.request` is its own module. You must have imported it. I can't replicate the behavior that you report.

Comment: @JohnColeman I didn't import it.  You can see the entire interpreter session.  Somehow, the act of trying to access `urllib.request` has a side effect that imports it.

Comment: If so, that is truly odd. When I tried the experiment I just got the same error message twice in a row. Are there other modules which autoload when you type their names a couple of times?

Comment: @JohnColeman I tried making my own module `foo` with a submodule `bar`, and this behavior did not happen.

Comment: I can't reproduce this behavior using the same version of Python (3.8.10). On what distribution are you running this?

Comment: @larsks 20.04.1-Ubuntu SMP

Comment: Does running the interpreter with `-v` show anything useful?

Comment: I can't reproduce this using Python 3.8.10 on Ubuntu 20.04, either, although I note that `python` on that distribution seems to lead to Python 2.7.18, whereas it is necessary to run `python3` to get Python 3.8.10.

Comment: @snakecharmerb Running with `-v` produces a whole lot of output, nearly 900 lines.  I have no idea what I'm looking for.

Comment: I wonder if it related to the Ubuntu behavior described [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/100971#issuecomment-1380995064)?